#  Advise on tackling syntax errors in Java

Tags: java

I very inexperience with Java, I'm spending ninety percent of time fixing errors in my program. Also when I experience a syntax error, it's super hard for me to spot them and fix them. I'll be very thankful if a experienced programmer can give some tips of the trade. An example of a type error for me is **Syntax error on token "void", @ expected**. On public void employeeName().

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmployeeDriver {

String employeeName;
public void employeeName() {
   try {

        Scanner scannerName = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Employye Name " + scannerName.nextLine());

        System.out.println("When did you hire the Employee");
        Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("The Employee name is " + scanner1.nextLine());

        System.out.println("What is the Employee's Number");
        Scanner scannerNum = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("The Employee name is " + scannerNum.nextLine());

    }catch (Exception e){
        System.out.println("Error occurred" + e.getMessage());
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("What is the Employee name");
    EmployeeDriver namingEmployeeObject = new EmployeeDriver();
    namingEmployeeObject.employeeName();
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
}
```

}

Comment: What are the ** before public and after employerName()? Clean them...  
More, please don't user UPPERCASE names for variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try given code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EmployeeDriver {
    String employeeName;

    public void employeeName() {
        try {
            Scanner scannerName = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Employye Name " + scannerName.nextLine());
            System.out.println("When did you hire the Employee");
            Scanner scanner1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("The Employee name is " + scanner1.nextLine());
            System.out.println("What is the Employee's Number");
            Scanner scannerNum = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("The Employee name is " + scannerNum.nextLine());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Error occurred" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("What is the Employee name");
        EmployeeDriver namingEmployeeObject = new EmployeeDriver();
        namingEmployeeObject.employeeName();
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Well, in this case the problem is that you're trying to declare one method (`employeeName`) within another (`main`). You can't do that.

As for how to find and fix such errors quickly: save and build *often*. If you're using Eclipse, that will compile as soon as you save, and I suspect other IDEs do the same.

That way, as soon as you've got a problem, you can hopefully remember what you've done since the code last *did* compile, and work out what's wrong. To be honest, compilers are *usually* pretty helpful these days.

Comment: Thank you very much, also do know a eclipse plugin that is better at debugging or find syntax errors?

Comment: @lonesarah: Not really - the built-in compiler does a pretty good job in my opinion.

Comment: I'm getting another error when I move the method like you said. Were should I move my employeeName method?

Comment: Okay I've found the right place to move my employeeName method. Now i'm getting a cannot be resolved to a variable error. it's two errors were employeeName methods are called in the try and catch methods.

Comment: @lonesarah: You're trying to use `employeeName` as if it's a field - it's not. Likewise `scanner` is a local variable in the `main` method, so you won't be able to use it directly in your other method - you may need to pass it as a parameter. To be honest, Stack Overflow isn't a good place to resolve this sort of thing - you're best off taking things slowly and carefully with a good book beside you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm probably going to get a lot of flack from the anti-IDE community, but I recommend you go download the free "Community Edition" of IntelliJ IDEA. This is a really slick Java IDE that will do real time syntax highlighting for you. You will be able to see what parts of the code have incorrect syntax, and why.

[IntelliJ IDEA Download](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/download/)

[An example of the Code Inspection features of IDEA](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/code_analysis.html)

Good luck.

Comment: Here it is :) No flack however. Suggesting an IDE to someone who doesn't know the syntax is plain wrong.

Comment: Thank you, any type of help will do.